# Python: Copying numbered questions from a file and pasting them into separate files with the number as the title for each

Tags: python

For hours, I have been trying to copy questions from a .txt file numbered from 1-8 and paste each question into its own separate .txt file with the names: (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, etc.).

Here is the .txt file:

```
1. (I) If the coefficient of kinetic friction between a 22-kg crate
and the floor is 0.30, what horizontal force is required to
move the crate at a steady speed across the floor? What
horizontal force is required if /Lk is zero?
2. (I) A force of 35.0 N is required to start a 6.0-kg box moving
across a horizontal concrete floor. (a) What is the coefficient
of static friction between the box and the floor? (b) If the
35.0-N force continues, the box accelerates at 0.60 m/s 2.
What is the coefficient of kinetic friction?
3. (I) Suppose you are standing on a train accelerating at 0.20 g.
What minimum coefficient of static friction must exist
between your feet and the floor if you are not to slide?
4. (I) The coefficient of static friction between hard rubber
and normal street pavement is about 0.90. On how steep a
hill (maximum angle) can you leave a car parked?
5. (I) What is the maximum acceleration a car can undergo if
the coefficient of static friction between the tires and the
ground is 0.90?
6. (II) (a) A box sits at rest on a rough 33° inclined plane.
Draw the free-body diagram, showing all the forces acting
on the box. (b) How would the diagram change if the box
were sliding down the plane. (c) How would it change if the
box were sliding up the plane after an initial shove?
```

I tried looping through the list and using if statements, with absolutely no luck. I have started over countless times but here is my latest code:

```
n = 1
stuff = open("copy.txt","r+")
new_file = "C:/Users/me/Desktop/DummyDirectory/" + str(n) + ".txt"
destination = open(new_file,"a") 

n = 1
question_number = str(n) + ". "     #note: there is a space next to the 
decimal
question_number_plus_1 = str(n + 1) + ". "

for the_line in stuff:
    reached_question_number = question_number in the_line

while n < 11:
    if reached_question_number:
        for the_line in stuff:
            if question_number_plus_1 not in the_line:
                destination.write(the_line)
            elif question_number_plus_1 in the_line:
                pass
            break
    n += 1
    stuff.seek(0)
```

Sorry if this code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Edit the part of .txt file I think making it harder to understand the situation @kuro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your text file, there are two types of lines...

1. Lines that start with a number and then a `"."`
2. Lines that do not start with a number and then a `"."`

The latter class of lines always is meant to be joined with the first class.

We can use this to come up with an algorithm.

1. If the line starts with a number and a dot, close currently open file (if present), open a new file, write the line to it.
2. If the line does not start with a number and a dot, write the line to the currently open file.

How you implement this is up to you -- But I like to think of these as groups, so I'd recommend using `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
import re
NUM_RE = re.compile(r'(^\d+\.)')

def get_line_num(line):
    match = NUM_RE.match(line)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)

with open('questions.txt', 'r') as text:
    file_obj = None
    for line_num, group in itertools.groupby(text, key=get_line_num):
        if line_num:
            if file_obj:
                file_obj.close()
            file_obj = open(line_num + 'txt', 'w')
            file_obj.writelines(group)
        else:
            file_obj.writelines(group)

    file_obj.close()
```

Of course, this could be made more robust (what about files where there is header text before the `"1."` question?)... Since that behavior is unspecified, I'll leave it unspecified here too ;-)

Comment: This solution seemed to work very well except that there was a confusion with line 8 beginning with "35.0-N force". How can I define line numbers as:  (integer +  "." + "[space]")?

Comment: EDIT: I implemented the fix that I asked for above by doing the following: (1) NUM_RE = re.compile(r'(^\d+\.)') --> NUM_RE = re.compile(r'(^\d+\. )') (2) file_obj = open(line_num + 'txt', 'w') --> file_obj = open(line_num.strip() + 'txt', 'w'). Thanks.

Comment: @ChristianChimezie -- It looks like you added a space in the regex.  You can also use `'(^\d+\.\s)'` (`\s` means a whitespace character).  You can also change the grouping to exclude the whitespace to avoid needing to strip the `line_num`:  `'(^\d+\.)\s'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can split with the first dot in each line of your input file to get the file name and the question. With that in hand you can write it to a new file!

```
with open('input.txt','r') as file:
    for question in file:
        file_name,question = question.split('.',1)
        with open(file_name+'.txt','w') as file:
            file.write(question)
```

That is,

on having a print after split(`print 'Filename: %s\nQuestion: %s'%(file_name,question)`), you can see

```
Filename: 1
Question: (I) If the coefficient of kinetic friction between a 22-kg crate and the floor is 0.30, what horizontal force is required to move the crate at a steady speed across the floor? What horizontal force is required if /Lk is zero?

Filename: 2
Question: (I) A force of 35.0 N is required to start a 6.0-kg box moving across a horizontal concrete floor. (a) What is the coefficient of static friction between the box and the floor? (b) If the 35.0-N force continues, the box accelerates at 0.60 m/s 2. What is the coefficient of kinetic friction?

Filename: 3
Question: (I) Suppose you are standing on a train accelerating at 0.20 g. What minimum coefficient of static friction must exist between your feet and the floor if you are not to slide?

Filename: 4
Question: (I) The coefficient of static friction between hard rubber and normal street pavement is about 0.90. On how steep a hill (maximum angle) can you leave a car parked?

Filename: 5
Question: (I) What is the maximum acceleration a car can undergo if the coefficient of static friction between the tires and the ground is 0.90?

Filename: 6
Question: (II) (a) A box sits at rest on a rough 33° inclined plane. Draw the free-body diagram, showing all the forces acting on the box. (b) How would the diagram change if the box were sliding down the plane. (c) How would it change if the box were sliding up the plane after an initial shove?
```

Comment: This is assuming that the questions take up a single line in the text file ... It's not clear to me that is a good assumption from the question (though it may be ... hopefully OP can clarify)

Comment: Exactly. that isnt mentioned in the question. So those cases can actually be handled with some slight modification to the above code, if clarified.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention it, but the questions do not take up a single line each, unfortunately. This is part of why it has been so difficult for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and just make sure you have a new line after each question.
Thumbs up

```
  file_id=0
    with open('q.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if len(line) > 1:
                print line
                file_id+=1
                with open(str(file_id)+'.txt','w') as f2:
                            f2.write(line)
```